# How to SELECT partial entity, and then use the entity update the entity in the database?

Tags: hibernate

I have an entity class with about 70 columns. The table may have around 200,000 rows. I want to update just one of the columns for all the 200,000 records.

Normally I would retrieve all the entities, and for each one, update the entity with the new value for the field, and save it.

The HQL would look something like this: `select p from Person p`. This allows us to write Java code such as: `entity.PhoneNumber = new_value; session.flush();`. The problem is that the SELECT will retrieve ALL 70 columns, when only 2 are required (the primary key and the field to be changed).

We could write HQL like this: `select p.Id, p.PhoneNumber from Person p`. Unfortunately now we're not getting entities anymore, so now rather than programming in an object-oriented way, we're now stuck with writing HQL: `update Person set p.PhoneNumber = ? where Id = ?`.

Is there a way to load a PARTIAL entity (load an entity with only some of the fields filled, and then use that object to make a change and then save it?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-select-clause)

1) For the first part of your question answer is positive. You can declare an entity constructor like the following

```java
@Entity
public class Person
{
   public Person(){} // The jpa required default constructor

   public Person(Long id, String phone){
      this.id = id;
      this.phoneNumber = phone;
   }
   ...
}
```

and then use it in the following way:

```
select new com.entity.Person(p.Id, p.PhoneNumber)
from Person p
```

2) But according to the same link:

> The projection class must be fully qualified in the entity query, and it must define a matching constructor. The class here need not be mapped. It can be a DTO class. **If it does represent an entity, the resulting instances are returned in the NEW state (not managed!).**

You can not expect synchronization with database after updating of this instance of entity. So, answer for the second part of your question is negative.